# Rails API multiple databases with session middleware not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rails-api, multiple-databases

The error I am getting is

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
- actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:235:in `load!'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:230:in `load_for_write!'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:216:in `merge!'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:19:in `create'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:71:in `prepare_session'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:265:in `context'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector.rb:53:in `block in call'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in read_from_replica'
        - activesupport (6.1.3.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:62:in `block in read_from_replica'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:383:in `block (2 levels) in with_role_and_shard'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1025:in `while_preventing_writes'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:381:in `block in with_role_and_shard'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:398:in `swap_connection_handler'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:373:in `with_handler'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:380:in `with_role_and_shard'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:175:in `connected_to'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:61:in `read_from_replica'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:39:in `read'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector.rb:63:in `select_database'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector.rb:52:in `call'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
```

or

```
undefined method `id' for {}:Hash

- rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:329:in `current_session_id'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:313:in `load_session'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:45:in `block in load_session'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `stale_session_check!'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:45:in `load_session'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:234:in `load!'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:230:in `load_for_write!'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:216:in `merge!'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:19:in `create'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:71:in `prepare_session'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:265:in `context'
        - rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
        - actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector.rb:53:in `block in call'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in read_from_replica'
        - activesupport (6.1.3.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:62:in `block in read_from_replica'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:383:in `block (2 levels) in with_role_and_shard'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1025:in `while_preventing_writes'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:381:in `block in with_role_and_shard'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:398:in `swap_connection_handler'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:373:in `with_handler'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:380:in `with_role_and_shard'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:175:in `connected_to'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:61:in `read_from_replica'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector/resolver.rb:39:in `read'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector.rb:63:in `select_database'
        - activerecord (6.1.3.1) lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector.rb:52:in `call'
```

I created a new rails api only app with `rails new my_api --api --database=postgresql`

I set up multiple database functionality as per the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html) say.

I add session middleware back into my api so I followed the [docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#using-session-middlewares)

The following are the only changes I have made to a fresh app

```
require_relative "boot"

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
require "action_text/engine"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.1

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.
    config.api_only = true


    # This also configures session_options for use below
    config.session_store :cache_store, key: '_app_session_key'

    # Required for all session management (regardless of session_store)
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies

    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options

    config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
    config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
    config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session

  end
end
```